# Google Analytics for Android v4 Auto Screen Measurement Opt-out for Activity

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

From what I can see in the logs, Google Analytics when using Automatic Screen Measurement, it'll log every single activity, even the ones unnamed in the tracker config .xml.

Is there a way for an Activity to opt-out of this automatic tracking, for some activities that tracking is not meaningful or inappropriate?

Comment: Have you tried setting the screen name to empty in the tracker config xml?

Comment: The response to this question solved this for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31279771/google-analytics-automatic-activity-detection-can-you-exclude-a-single-activit