# Google Analytics Automatic Activity Detection - can you exclude a single activity from this?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

Automatic activity detection is great - except my `MainActivity` is a bunch of different fragments with a nav drawer (like Google Play Music or the Play Store). I am using manual screen hitting to track the fragments in that activity.

Therefore, an automatic screen hit for my `MainActivity` is meaningless and pollutes my stats. Can I exclude my `MainActivity` from being tracked in this manner?

Reference: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/screens#automatic

Answer (score 0):

Just set `enableAutoActivityTracking(false)`to the Tracker instance obtained in the activity.

Assuming that you created a `getDefaultTracker()` method in your Application class as described in [the official docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#application), you can create a parent class for your application activities that can change *auto-tracking* behavior on demand:

```
public abstract class ParentActivity extends Activity {

    Tracker mTracker = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getTracker();
    }

    /* Obtains Google Analytics Tracker for this activity */
    Tracker getTracker() {
        if (mTracker == null) {
            AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
            mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
            // Enable or disable auto-tracking for this activity
            mTracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(shouldAutoTrack());
        }
        return mTracker;
    }

    /* Defines whether this activity should enable auto-track or not. Default is true. */
    protected boolean shouldAutoTrack() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Your main activity just have to extend ParentActivity and override `shouldAutoTrack` method to return false:

```
public class MainActivity extends ParentActivity {

    /* Disable auto-tracking for this activity */
    protected boolean shouldAutoTrack() {
        return false;
    }

}
```